# Read in Comma separated list of files, output without commas without iteration

Tags: java, regex, replace

I'm trying to remove the commas from the following txt file:

```
abcd,efgh,ijkl
mnop,qrst,uvwx
yzzz,0123,4567
8910
```

My code goes something like this:

```
public static ArrayList readFileByLine(ArrayList list, String fileName){
try{
    File file = new File(fileName);
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(file);
    reader.useDelimiter(",");
    while(reader.hasNext()){
      String s = reader.next();
      s= s.trim();
      s= s.replaceAll("," , "");
      list.add(s);
    }
    reader.close();
}
catch(FileNotFoundException e){ System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());}

return list;
```

}

I'm trying not to use a regex unless absolutely necessary, if you recommend that I use a regex please explain what it does!   Thanks for the help!

Comment: What happens when you run that code? I'm guessing something's not working properly?

Comment: Replaceall requires a regex, and unfortunately regex and I have a salty relationship...

Comment: I've also tried using replace, but it won't pick up just a comma, so I'm out of luck there too.  Using substr breaks the iteration rule...So I think I'm stuck using a regex.

Comment: I just tested your code, and it worked fine. What was the issue again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code runs fine. I think you were running into other issues, I'm not sure what. Here's the code that I used (your code with some modifications):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        List<String> list = readFileByLine(new ArrayList<String>(), "/Users/hassan/Library/Containers/com.apple.TextEdit/Data/Desktop/file.text");
        for(String s : list){
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }

    public static List<String> readFileByLine(ArrayList<String> list, String fileName){
        try{
            File file = new File(fileName);
            Scanner reader = new Scanner(file);
            reader.useDelimiter(",");
            while(reader.hasNext()){
              String s = reader.next();
              s= s.trim();
              s= s.replaceAll("," , "");
              list.add(s);
            }
            reader.close();
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e){ System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());}

        return list;
    }
}
```

This code works (try it!). I should mention that the way I'm using this code, passing an ArrayList as the first argument is useless, since you can just make a new ArrayList at the beginning of the `readFileByLine` function. I'm not sure if you did it this way because you want to re-add strings to the array later on, so I left it alone.